# Is there React Native Custom SDK for Razorpay

Tags: android, react-native, razorpay

I am trying to integrating Razorpay in my react-native app but there is only standard SDK for it. I didn't find any custom SDK for Razorpay react-native. I founded it for Android integration (https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/android-integration/custom/additional-features/). Please suggest me if there is any Custom SDK for React-native Razorpay integration or any other option for the same.

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/razorpay/react-native-razorpay First hit on github.com. Looks maintained as well

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! I have already gone through https://github.com/razorpay/react-native-razorpay but I didn't found  Additional support for the payment method for react-native like this https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/android-integration/standard/payment-methods/#save-customer-data.

Answer (score 0):

**Call this function and edit informations .......**
*works for me*

```
  const Paymentgateway = () => {
        var options = {
          description: 'Credits towards consultation',
          // image: 'https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.jpg',
          currency: 'INR',
          key: '<YOUR_KEY_ID>',
          amount: '5000',
          name: 'Acme Corp',
          order_id: 'order_DslnoIgkIDL8Zt', //Replace this with an order_id created using Orders API.
          prefill: {
            email: 'user123@gmail.com',
            contact: '9191919191',
            name: 'user',
          },
          theme: {color: '#53a20e'},
        };
        RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
          .then(data => {
            // handle success
            alert(`Success: ${data.razorpay_payment_id}`);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // handle failure
            alert(`Error: ${error.code} | ${error.description}`);
          });
      };
```